# Redash container broke on "worker" in Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, aws-fargate, redash

I use the recommended Redash [docker image](https://github.com/getredash/redash) , docker-compose tested locally, all services are up & running. (server, scheduler, worker, redis, postgres) http://localhost:5000/setup is up and running

```
% docker-compose up -d
Docker Compose is now in the Docker CLI, try `docker compose up`

Creating network "redash_default" with the default driver
Creating redash_postgres_1 ... done
Creating redash_redis_1    ... done
Creating redash_server_1           ... done
Creating redash_scheduler_1        ... done
Creating redash_adhoc_worker_1     ... done
Creating redash_scheduled_worker_1 ... done
Creating redash_nginx_1            ... done
% docker-compose run --rm server create_db
Creating redash_server_run ... done
[2021-10-29 23:53:52,904][PID:1][INFO][alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
[2021-10-29 23:53:52,905][PID:1][INFO][alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
[2021-10-29 23:53:52,933][PID:1][INFO][alembic.runtime.migration] Running stamp_revision  -> 89bc7873a3e0
```

I build the image from this version & push to ECR, configured Fargate Task Definition to run from this image. In task definition I mapped ports (6379, 5432, 5000, 80 any possible ports). The task is showing worker timed out.

```
2021-10-29 18:31:08[2021-10-29 23:31:08,742][PID:6104][DEBUG][redash.query_runner] Registering Vertica (vertica) query runner.
2021-10-29 18:31:08[2021-10-29 23:31:08,744][PID:6104][DEBUG][redash.query_runner] Registering ClickHouse (clickhouse) query runner.
2021-10-29 18:31:08[2021-10-29 23:31:08 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:6103)
[2021-10-29 23:31:08 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:6103)
2021-10-29 18:31:08[2021-10-29 23:31:08 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:6104)
2021-10-29 18:31:08[2021-10-29 23:31:08 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:6105)
2021-10-29 18:31:08[2021-10-29 23:31:08 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:6106)
2021-10-29 18:31:08[2021-10-29 23:31:08 +0000] [6106] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 6106)
2021-10-29 18:31:08[2021-10-29 23:31:08 +0000] [6105] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 6105)
```

I manually added two environmental variables REDASH_REDIS_URL & REDASH_DATABASE_URL. They are not working either. My EC2 can access RDS, so it's not the db problem.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-8-0-191:~$ psql -h p-d-mt-a-redash-rds-instance-1.c5clgmj5xaif.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 -U postgresPassword for user postgres: 
psql (10.18 (Ubuntu 10.18-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), server 13.4)
WARNING: psql major version 10, server major version 13.
         Some psql features might not work.
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 mytable   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 rdsadmin  | rdsadmin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | rdsadmin=CTc/rdsadmin
 template0 | rdsadmin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/rdsadmin          +
           |          |          |             |             | rdsadmin=CTc/rdsadmin
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(5 rows)

postgres=>
```

Does anyone know how to make the "WORKER" working? (not timed out, exit) Does it need a lot of configuration in order to make Redash launched by Fargate? BTW, I created Redis & RDS in AWS. They are all the same VPC, security group inbound configured too.